# Accounting for "Glued" Edges in Finding Boundary Curves of Parametrized Surfaces

Tags: surfaces, transformation, parametrization

Let $T: [0,2] \times [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be defined by $T(r,\theta) = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta, r)$, which parametrizes a cylinder with radius $1$ and height $2$.

To find the boundary curve of this surface (or any other surface), a common approach is to find where each segment of the domain ended up by parametrizing each segment as $\sigma$ and then composing $T(\sigma)$. However, this method does not take into account the effect of "gluing" two edges together.

For example, if we take a rectangular ribbon and glue two opposite edges together to form a cylinder the new cylinder has two boundary curves instead of four like the original paper ribbon, the method i described earlier, would still count those two glued segments as a part of the boundary curve even though its not.

How can I fix the method in order to consider "glued" edges?

concrete example with the cylinder:

- $s_1(t)=(t,0), t\in[0,2]$
- $s_2(t)=(2,t), t\in[0,2\pi]$
- $s_3(t)=(2-t,2\pi),t\in[0,2]$
- $s_4(t)=(0,2\pi-t),t\in[0,2\pi]$

each $s_n$ segment corresponds to a side of the domain rectangle, or the "edges" of the rectangle, now if I compose $T(s_n)$ i should obtain the boundary curve of the surface T :

- $T(s_1)=(0,0,t), t\in[0,2]$,
- $T(s_2)=(cos(t),sin(t),0), t\in[0,2\pi]$,
- $T(s_3)=(0,0,2-t),t\in[0,2]$ and
- $T(s_4)=(cos(t),-sin(t),0),t\in[0,2\pi]$.

Both $T(s_2)$ and $T(s_4)$ belong in the boundary curve of T, though $T(s_1)$ and $T(s_3)$ do not.

Comment: Your post is difficult to understand. Your terminology --- particularly "folding" --- does not have a standard meaning, and I don't know how to guess what meaning you might have in mind. At the very least, perhaps you can give some explicit examples, with actual formulas, that illustrate what you mean by "folding".

Comment: yes. Im sorry about that, i dont speak english and i dont quite know how to explain it. If I have a paper ribbon and i wanted to make a cylinder with it, i would eventually have to glue two edges together, if i have a T(theta,z)=(cos(theta), sin(theta), z), T:[0,2pi]x[0,2]->R^3. The rectangle of the domain has 4 edges since its a rectangle, but the surface only has 2 edges, because I "folded" two edges together. I just mean that you loose edges when you transform a domain and i dont know how to identify that given any parametrized surface. perhaps an image may help?

Comment: I re wrote the post